# Apache port based virtual host redirects to folder

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to set up Apache to serve different folders for different ports using virtual hosts.

I have set apache to listen on port 8081, opened the port and set up a virtual host like so :

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>

 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-folder
 </VirtualHost>
```

This however redirects requests to myip:8081 to myip/my-folder, how can I set so it opens myip:8081 as the root address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `NameVirtualHost *:8081` in the config, and it should work.

According to apache documentation: [Running different sites on different ports.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#port)

> You have multiple domains going to the same IP and also want to serve
>   multiple ports. By defining the ports in the "**NameVirtualHost**" tag,
>   you can allow this to work. If you try using `<VirtualHost name:port>`
>   without the `NameVirtualHost name:port` or you try to use the `Listen`
>   directive, your configuration will not work.